# Adding data to an array list which is contained inside an object

Tags: java

I currently have three main classes. A tv series class which contains an object and its getters and setters:

```
public class TVSeries {
private String title;
private Genre genre;
private Rating rating;
private int numOfEps;
private ArrayList<String> actor = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<Integer> listOfReviews = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public TVSeries(String title, Genre genre, Rating rating, int numOfEps, ArrayList<String> actor, ArrayList<Integer> listOfReviews) {
    this.title = title;
    this.genre = genre;
    this.rating = rating;
    this.numOfEps = numOfEps;
    this.actor = actor;
    this.listOfReviews = listOfReviews;
```

A series library class which is an object made up of just a arraylist tv series objects:

```
public class SeriesLibrary {
private ArrayList<TVSeries> tvSeries = new ArrayList<TVSeries>();

public SeriesLibrary(ArrayList<TVSeries> tvSeries) {
    this.tvSeries = tvSeries;
}

public ArrayList<TVSeries> getTvSeries() {
    return tvSeries;
}

public void setTvSeries(ArrayList<TVSeries> tvSeries) {
    this.tvSeries = tvSeries;
}

public TVSeries addTVSeries(Scanner sc) {
    System.out.println("Add a new TV Series");
    System.out.println("------------------------------");
    System.out.print("Please enter the TV series' Title: ");
    String title = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Please enter the TV series' Genre: ");
    String strGenre = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Please enter the TV series' Age Rating: ");
    String strRating = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Please enter the number of Episodes in the TV Series: ");
    int numOfEps = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println(title + " will be set up with no actors or ratings. These can be added later.");
    ArrayList<String> emptyActors = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> emptyReviews = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Genre genre = Genre.valueOf(strGenre);
    Rating rating = Rating.valueOf(strRating);
    TVSeries newSeries = new TVSeries(title, genre, rating, numOfEps, emptyActors, emptyReviews);
    return newSeries;
}
```

And a tester class. I am putting the code to add this data in a menu but i don't really know how to start it.

I have a method within the series library class which allows users to add information to create a new tv series and the method returns their newly created object.

Within the tester what code would i use to add this new value to the array list within the object, called seriesLibrary for example. Do i have to create a new method? Do i alter my current method?

Comment: For some reason the previous comments are coming up as deleted, as well as mine, i have edited the post to include my current code.

Comment: have you checked the answers below? If you're satisfied with one of the answers please mark it as a solution. Else comment and say what's wrong!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly but you could do the following:

```
ArrayList<TVSeries> tvSeriesLibrary = seriesLibrary.getTvSeries();
tvSeriesLibrary.add(newSeriesToAdd);
seriesLibrary.setTvSeries(tvSeriesLibrary);
```

This is assuming `seriesLibrary` is your already initialized `SeriesLibrary` object and `newSeriesToAdd` is the object returned from creating a new `TVSeries` object.

Answer (score 0):

As your method requests a `Scanner` as argument, you could for example create a file (a txt-file) where you typed all the information you're asking in your method, create a `Scanner` that reads your file and then pass that `Scanner` to your method. That's a solution to your specific problem.

I would advise you to change your method though. Because of the low testability of methods that require reading/scanning data from I/O channels (files, streams, stdin, ...) I always have as habit to separate the scanning/reading part of my program and code representing some kind of logic operation. So my advice would be to create a separate function that reads/scans the data you're asking for and then passes all this data to methods that will process that data (in your case, create the `TVSeries` with the correct values based on that data). In your case it could be something like this:

```
public TVSeries addTVSeriesFromInput(Scanner sc) {
    System.out.println("Add a new TV Series");
    System.out.println("------------------------------");
    System.out.print("Please enter the TV series' Title: ");
    String title = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Please enter the TV series' Genre: ");
    String strGenre = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Please enter the TV series' Age Rating: ");
    String strRating = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Please enter the number of Episodes in the TV Series: ");
    int numOfEps = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println(title + " will be set up with no actors or ratings. These can be added later.");
    return addTVSeries(title, strGentre, strRating, numOfEps);
}

public TVSeries addTVSeries(String title, String strGenre, String strRating, int numOfEps){ 
    ArrayList<String> emptyActors = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> emptyReviews = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Genre genre = Genre.valueOf(strGenre);
    Rating rating = Rating.valueOf(strRating);
    TVSeries newSeries = new TVSeries(title, genre, rating, numOfEps, emptyActors, emptyReviews);
    return newSeries;
}
```

PS: I find it very strange that your method is called `addTVSeries` but it only creates a new `TVSeries` object whithout adding it to the list `tvSeries`